# ORA-01461-can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

Tags: java, sql, oracle

When I want to commit transaction, I get this error:

> ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

I save multiple entity in this transaction- How can I find where the problem is

Comment: The `LONG` data type has been deprecated about two decades ago, you shouldn't be using it to begin with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ORA-01461 can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column

```
Cause: An attempt was made to insert a value from a LONG datatype into another 
datatype. This is not allowed.

**Action**: Do not try to insert LONG datatypes into other types of columns.

**Answer**:  The LONG and LONG RAW datatypes have been deprecated and the easiest solution to the ORA-01461 error is to change the column datatype to as CLOB.
```

Comment: I understand.I got this error cause I didn't set @manyToOne relation and the type of column in table was Raw so I cant insert long value in a column that has raw  data type. Thank you the "Raw" keyword help me

Answer (score 0):

This error may also occur if you try to insert a string containing non printable character(s)

e.g. c2a0 due to character set conversion issues